# Ipv4 and 6 cannot find ip address

Tags: networking

Can't upload pic but here is what my network says

Ipv6 address:  fe80::846b:5b0:4e1a:faf2%8/64
Default gateway:  fe80::201:5cff:fe9c:9246%8

I'm no expert but I don't think the ip should look this way.

Issue: unidentified network no internet. When renewing ip config nothing appears below it in admin command prompt. I've tried all the different command prompts I could find, including netsh Winsock and such.

Any help is appreciated. If anyone needs more information let me know.

Comment: Go to CMD.. and type ipconfig. Or window+ r. Type ncpa.cpl. you can see the network adaptor. Check which is the one you are connected. Right click on that go to status.

Answer (score 0):

These are IPv6 link-local addresses. It's normal and required to have one, although *not enough* for Internet communications. Usually you should have both a global and a link-local addresses.

The gateway can be any type of address, as long as it is from an on-link subnet; it doesn't make any difference.

If you don't have IPv4, the protocol may simply have been disabled in network settings (ncpa.cpl)?